# Variant on: Is it better to Daven "too early" with a Minyan, or to Daven alone at the right time?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, priorities

In many communities there is a regular weekday morning Minyan and the "working-person's" Minyan, which technically Davens too early according to most opinions, but which is better than nothing, according to other opinions. But, again, many opinions hold that it is far better to Daven "at the right time" all alone than "too early" with a Minyan. This is how my Rav in Yeshivah Paskened.

In a slight twist, I'd like to ask the following:
If someone will have a slight chance of Davening alone at the proper time (Zeman), should he forgo Davening with a Minyan that definitely Davens too early? What if the odds are stacked against him that he will likely miss the Zeman anyway and have to Daven late or do Tashlumin (make-up)?

Comment: Aren't your two cases ("someone will have a slight chance of Davening (praying) alone in the right Zeman" and "he will likely miss the Zeman anyway and have to Daven late") identical? (Also, what's "anyway"?)

Comment: How early is too early?

Comment: @msh210 assume for the first one his chances are kinda reasonable but not altogether that likely. He'll need to sneak away from an important meeting or conference but he could do it if he's sitting in the back and the lights are dim. There's also a short break in the middle.  Assume for the second case he's presenting at the meeting. There's still that break, but what if someone tries to chat with him? (These are realistic but not real life examples. I thought I should make that clear. For real situations CYLOR.)

Comment: @doubleaa For sure before Netz.

Comment: @SethJ Well you should know that your question doesn't even mention the fact that you are talking about shacharit. I think it's quite unclear.

Comment: Touche. In any event, I think it's relevant in other situations as well. Let's say the only way he can Daven Ma'ariv is before Sheki'ah (but there's a Minyan) but he just finished Minhah a minute before they are about to start (he was running late) and there are obstacles possibly preventing him from Davening all the rest of the night (he's a security guard or a medical resident on his first ever night shift at his new assignment. Getting away will be very difficult indeed.

Comment: @SethJ There are way too many permutations of this for one question. Shacharit can be before SZT, before SZKSh, before hanetz, before misheyakir, before alot hashachar. Mincha can be before tzeit, before shkiya shniya (for RT), before regular shkiya, before plag, before mincha ketana, before mincha gedola, before chatzot. Maariv can be before alot hashachar, before chatzot, before tzeit, before shkiya, before plag. This doesn't account for how these interact with each other (ie relying on two contradictory kullot). Each of these cases can have different considerations.You need to be more spcfc

Comment: One part of the question that doesn't make sense to me, is that one can be in a room with a minyan, and answer to minyany things, even while they plan on davening again later at the correct time, or even if they davened at the correct time before the late minyan.

Comment: @DoubleAA Point(s) taken. I've revised the question and posted a separate question elsewhere.

Comment: @avi I'm assuming he has a choice - he can go to Minyan or he can not. The question is not whether he is already there and can listen. If you want to suggest that it is better to go and listen even if he doesn't join them, please feel free to make that case in an answer.

Comment: @SethJ Yes, I meant going to a minyan even if just to be a part of it.

Comment: Did your rav paskin that it was better to daven later in a case where you have to run to work or not? It seems that the halacha is that one may daven before hanetz if he is rushing off somewhere (SA OC 89:8). One may debate what to do if the only minyan available is before hanetz but you are in no rush. It sounds from your question that you are in a case of 'rush'. So it seems the 'workers minyan' is lechatchila for you! I think your rav was referring to a case where you had nowhere to rush to and just there was only one minyan available. But CYLOR :) (see goo.gl/0QnlQ at the end for more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terumat HaDeshen ([Siman 35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14655&st=&pgnum=21)) discusses regarding kiddush levana, if it is better to wait to say it on Saturday night (its ideal time) or to say it right away (as we generally do not delay doing mitzvot because "zerizim makdimim"). He answers that if he is sure that he will be able to say kiddush levana on Saturday night he should wait. However if it is winter and there are only a few days left such that he can't know for sure that he will have another opportunity to say kiddush levana, then he should say it right away. In other words, we only push off a mitzva to perform it in a more optimal way if we are confident of being succesful; otherwise, it is not worth the risk.

So too here, if he is unsure of being able to daven until after zman (or even not at all!) than he should daven as soon as possible, even before sunrise (which is the less than ideal time).

(But note my earlier [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13421/variant-on-is-it-better-to-daven-too-early-with-a-minyan-or-to-daven-alone-a#comment22815_13421) where I argue that davening before sunrise is not bedieved for someone who is rushing out somewhere which sounds exactly like your case. Also see [this article](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/halak58/08shachr.doc) and [this shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/765298/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Davening_Early_When_Neitz_is_Late) regarding early davening in general.)

Comment: How about a refocus on the BeDi'avad status? Is there nobody who says that Tefillah "too early" is invalid at all? Does everyone agree that at least in a situation where he may not get a chance to Daven later, that this extra-early Minyan at least offers him the chance to Daven and not just a chance for Berachoth Levataloth?

Comment: @SethJ Everyone agrees that tefilla after alot hashachar is kosher bedieved. For birkot keriat shema some say you have to wait until misheyakir. Assuming your minyan is holding of those times, it is not a beracha levatala lekulei alma.

Comment: @SethJ I edited some discussion in. Is this answering your intended question?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty good.

Comment: related http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=13451&rid=1092