# Should I close my eyes for the shmona esrei or look in the siddur?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, prayer-book, see-sight-vision-blind

I was taught to look in the siddur when davening.  But the answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35682/5120) suggests that some authorities prefer to close their eyes during the amida.

What are sources for all opinions on this matter?

Comment: Shabbos or weekday?

Comment: I did not know there is a difference, I want all sources

Comment: What will help you focus better?

Comment: @DoubleAA probably closed eyes is a lot less distracting but I will need to memorize it

Answer (score 6):

At the end of Pathway to Prayer, R" Birnbaum has the following sources:

Tanya Rabbosi, written in the 13th century, says to pray with a siddur.  So does the Vilna Gaon in Even Shleyma ch. 9 note 2, and the Chofetz Chaim at the end of Shem Olam.  R' Birnbaum asked R' Moshe Feinstein, and he said to daven with a siddur.

Sefer HaYoshar Shaar (13th century) Shaar 13 says to pray with closed eyes.

Mekor Chaim (17th century) 95:2 says it is better to pray with a siddur, but one should occasionally pray by heart because praying from a siddur will become habitual and cause concentration to diminish.

Answer (score 4):

There are conflicting opinions brought in the Mishna Berurah [93 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=251) & [95 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=254). But if one needs to keep their eyes open so they can read the words there is no problem. 
See here a nice synopsis. http://www.torah.org/learning/tefilah/openeyes.html

Comment: As of now i can't find the ba'er heitev(?) That discusses praying on shabbos specifically from a siddur, so we'll put that on hold.

Answer (score 2):

The [Maharsham in his Daas Torah 91:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41144&st=&pgnum=164) brings the opinion of the Arizal who held on shabbas one should not daven with his eyes closed ,but rather daven from a siddur.

Comment: Does he explain why Shabbat would be different?